# How can i do Swedish language in internet explorer by html | (HTML FOR WEB DESIGN TASK)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm facing a problem in internet explorer. I'm a website designer in a new label. My problem is the Swedish language not support in internet explorer. When I check it by google chrome, firefox then this language showing perfectly. I have to change Html lang="sv" but there is no change in internet explorer. Kindly Show my Screenshot Clearly and help me, please. It's will be very helpful for me

Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRWLC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pecb.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've noticed some quality problems with your post: Code is provided as screenshots, wrong use of markdown. Please read the [guide on how to ask good guestions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying to add this line in the head part of your HTML page may help you to display the Swedish text in the IE browser.

```
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Tested code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="sv" >
<head>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
Video är ett kraftfullt sätt att hjälpa dig bevisa din poäng. När du klickar på Online Video kan du klistra in bädda in kod för den video du vill lägga till. Du kan också skriva ett nyckelord för att söka online efter den video som bäst passar ditt dokument.
</body>
</html>
```

Output in the IE 11 browser:

[image]